# Como aumentar as barras de um gráfico no R?

Tags: r

Alguém sabe qual é o comando para deixar mais largas as barras do gráfico gerado pelo código abaixo?

```
library(lattice)

rend <- read.table("http://www.leg.ufpr.br/~walmes/cursoR/rendimento.txt",
               header=TRUE, sep="\t")
 rend <- transform(rend, K=factor(K), A=factor(A), bloc=factor(bloc))
(rend$Trat = with(rend, interaction(K, A)))
(médias.Trat = with(rend, tapply(rg, Trat, mean)))
barchart(rg~K|A, groups=médias.Trat, data=rend)
```

Comment: Rui, acho que o AP passou os dados. Eles estão sendo baixados do link http://www.leg.ufpr.br/~walmes/cursoR/rendimento.txt . Mas creio que o problema não tem solução, não ao menos como o AP deseja. Quando faço `length(médias.Trat)`, obtenho 15. Isto implica que são 15 grupos sendo plotados. Ou seja, apesar de aparecerem apenas 5 barras em cada painel, são 15 barras no total, o que implica que as larguras das barras devem ser tais que caibam 15 delas em cada painel. A meu ver, é impossível resolver este problema sem diminuir o tamanho de `médias.Trat`.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não entendi muito bem a lógica do `groups=médias.Trat` e, infelizmente, ainda não tenho pontuação mínima para realizar comentário em perguntas. Deixo aqui minha breve contribuição e indicação para uso do pacote `ggplot2`.

```
...
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
rend_y <- data.frame(med_trat = médias.Trat) %>% 
  dplyr::add_rownames() %>%
  dplyr::rename("Trat" = rowname) %>% 
  dplyr::full_join(rend, by = "Trat") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Trat = as.factor(Trat))
rend_y %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = K, y = rg),
           stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(~A, scales = "free") +
  theme_light()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Sugiro atualizar a pergunta e expor alguma imagem para que possamos entender melhor qual o objetivo final do plot, além de tentar tornar as barras mais largas. Em caso de atualização da pergunta, posso atualizar a resposta. Talvez o caminho para solução esteja no objeto `rend_y`.